# Send an email with attachment and save in Google Drive using Google Apps Script

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, email-attachments

Hi everyone and thanks a lot for reading this.

I have some code that was based on SendPDF of Jiayao. Original here: [SendPDF of Jiayao](https://github.com/jiayao/Google-spreadsheet-PDF-sender)

I have a Google Spreadsheet that generates a PDF, send email, and save the pdf in Google Drive ( I using Google Apps).

It always worked. However, when I moved to the New Google Drive no longer works.

When I run I get the error:

`Request failed http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=1KWJC2tHk6uxrrIYwaf3GOe5NKsPzQRaYQy2pPmwfx_M&exportFormat=pdf&gid=954198957 retornou o código 401. Resposta truncada do servidor:< HTML >   < HEAD > < TITLE >Unauthorized  < BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"> < H1 >Unauthorized Error 401   (use a opção muteHttpExceptions para examinar a resposta completa)`

Below, my code:

```
// Copyright 2010 Jiayao Yu
//
// ORIGINAL See usage and updated version on http://gist.github.com/405466
var TOKEN_CELL = 1;
var EMAIL_CELL = 2;
var BCC_CELL = 3;
var SUBJECT_CELL = 4;
var BODY_CELL = 5;
var SHEET_NAME_CELL = 6;
var SHEET_RELATORIO = 7;
var SPREADSHEET_URL = "http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=";
var DATA_RELATORIO = 8;
var BUSCA_GID = 9;

function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      menuEntries = [ {name: "Enviar relatório", functionName: "sendAsPdf"}];
  ss.addMenu("Relatório HRT", menuEntries);
  var configSheet = getConfigSheet();
  configSheet.getRange(1, TOKEN_CELL).setValue("Auth Token");
  configSheet.getRange(1, EMAIL_CELL).setValue("Email");
  configSheet.getRange(1, BCC_CELL).setValue("Bcc");
  configSheet.getRange(1, SUBJECT_CELL).setValue("Subject");
  configSheet.getRange(1, BODY_CELL).setValue("htmlBody");
  configSheet.getRange(1, SHEET_NAME_CELL).setValue("Export sheet name");
  configSheet.getRange(1, SHEET_RELATORIO).setValue("Relatorio");
  configSheet.getRange(1, DATA_RELATORIO).setValue("DatadoRelatorio");
  configSheet.getRange(1, BUSCA_GID).setValue("BGID");
}

function sendAsPdf() {

 // Pergunta se deseja enviar email
  var PerguntaEmail = Browser.msgBox('Enviar Email', 'Deseja enviar email para ' + getConfig(EMAIL_CELL) , Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
  if (PerguntaEmail == 'yes' ) { 


        var configSheet = getConfigSheet();
        var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
        var sheetName = getConfig(SHEET_NAME_CELL);
        var arquivoName = getConfig(SHEET_NAME_CELL) + getConfig(SHEET_RELATORIO);
        var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

        if (!dataSheet) {
        Browser.msgBox("Can't find sheet named:" + sheetName);
        return;
                        }

// Atualiza a data do Relatório na aba Relatorio_Pneumologia

//    Browser.msgBox(getConfig(DATA_RELATORIO));
//    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd-MM-yyyy");    
          dataSheet.getRange(3,2).setValue(getConfig(DATA_RELATORIO));
//     Logger.log(formattedDate);
//    Browser.msgBox(formattedDate);


// Envia EMAIL

          var dataSheetIndex = dataSheet.getIndex() - 1;

// Original: var url = SPREADSHEET_URL + id + "&exportFormat=pdf&gid=" + dataSheetIndex;

          var url = SPREADSHEET_URL + id + "&exportFormat=pdf&gid=" + getConfig(BUSCA_GID);
          var auth = "AuthSub token=\"" + getConfig(TOKEN_CELL) + "\"";
          var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {Authorization: auth}});
          var content = res.getContent();

          var responseCode = res.getResponseCode();
          if (responseCode != 200 || res.getContentText().indexOf("/ServiceLoginAuth") != -1) {
          Logger.log("Fetch url:" + url + " failed with " + responseCode);
          Browser.msgBox("Error occurred when exporting spreadsheet to pdf, it might be caused by auth token being expired");
          return;
                                                                                               }

          var bcc = getConfig(BCC_CELL);
          Logger.log("BCC to:" + bcc);
          var attachments = [{fileName:arquivoName + ".pdf", content: content, mimeType:"application/pdf"}];
          MailApp.sendEmail(getConfig(EMAIL_CELL), getConfig(SUBJECT_CELL),
          "", {attachments:attachments, bcc: bcc, htmlBody: getConfig(BODY_CELL)});

          Browser.msgBox("Email enviado com sucesso para: " + getConfig(EMAIL_CELL));


// Salvar versao do relatório no Google Drive

          var Impressao = Browser.msgBox('Salvar Relatorio', 'Deseja salvar o relatório no Google Drive?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
          if (Impressao == 'yes' ) { 

// Codigo inspirado em http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881547/exporting-spreadsheet-to-pdf-then-saving-the-file-in-google-drive

// Salva no Google Drive

                      var NomedoArquivo = arquivoName + ".pdf"
                      DocsList.createFile(res).rename(NomedoArquivo);;
                      Browser.msgBox('Arquivo gravado em seu Google Drive. Pode fechar da planilha.');
                                  } 
                      else { Browser.msgBox('Operação concluída com sucesso. Pode fechar da planilha.')
                           }

                      }

// FIM DO THEN do IF se deseja enviar email   

                     else { Browser.msgBox('Ok. Pode fechar da planilha.')
                          }

// FIM DO IF se deseja enviar email

// FIM DA FUNCAO - sendAsPdf

}

function getConfig(cell) {
  var configSheet = getConfigSheet();
  return configSheet.getRange(2, cell).getValue();
}

function getConfigSheet() {
  var name = "script_config";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name);
  if (!sheet) {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(name);
    Logger.log("Created sheet " + name);
  }
  return sheet;
}
```

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Can you please post the english version of the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version of spreadsheets use a different url for file conversion, that's why your script is not working anymore.

You have 2 possible solutions :

- Use the advanced drive service as shown in [Eric Koleda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985703/converting-google-spreadsheet-to-xlsx-or-ods-using-gas/25205566#25205566) which can provide multiple export formats
- Use the simple `getAs('application/pdf')` from the [Drive service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getAs(String)) since pdf is the only supported format (for now) and that's what you are using !

The returned value is a blob, you can use it directly to create your file in Drive.

Comment: Thank you Serge. I modified the code as your suggested. It worked. Thank you very much.